# Adding a Json service to my ASP.Net Web Api causes a change in the format of the response in Postman

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

In Program.cs without the specific Json service:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Postman Json Response (The one I prefer):

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Central Park",
    "description": "The most visited urban park in the United States."
}
```

In Program.cs with the specific Json service:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Postman Response that wont be Json (The one I truly despise):

```
<PointsOfInterestDto xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CityInfo.API.Models"><Description>The most visited urban park in the United States.</Description><Id>1</Id><Name>Central Park</Name></PointsOfInterestDto>
```

How do I achieve a Json response?

Comment: why you have `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters`? cant you remove it?

Answer (score -1):

`AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()` was the issue...

Change to:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddNewtonsoftJson();
```